# Download microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.Adaptive

Tags: botframework, bots

I am not able find the microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.Adaptive preview dll , please let me know how to download the dll

Thanks & Regards,
Vinoth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under BotBuilder's Myget packages repo, not NuGet, see here: https://botbuilder.myget.org/feed/botbuilder-declarative/package/nuget/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive

Comment: I tried is not working 
Error Message :  
nstall-Package : NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive. No packages exist with this id in source(s): https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/aspnet-aspnetcore-tooling/index.json,

Comment: your feed is incorrect. See myget page, feed url is `https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-declarative/api/v3/index.json` for nuget v3

Comment: I went URL which you sent first, here is the link I have executed in the VS "Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive -Version 4.6.0-Daily-2019-06-05-01 -Source https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/botbuilder-declarative/api/v3/index.json" its not installed

Comment: I tried: got an error when trying to directly use this command, but it's OK once you add the source in your Nuget sources (Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings, then "Package sources")